# trying to copy data from a prepopulated collection to an associated array in a function

Tags: oracle

I am getting below error while trying to copy data from one collection to other.

```
Error(17,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COLUMN_VALUE": invalid identifier
```

Please help me providing a better way.

```
create or replace type type_record as object(employee_id NUMBER(6),
                                             first_name VARCHAR2(20));
create or replace type type_tbl as table of type_record;

create or replace function scrub_final_2 return sys_refcursor IS
  x type_tbl;   
  test1 type_tbl;                             
  y sys_refcursor;
  z sys_refcursor;
begin
  x:=type_tbl();
  z:=scrub_final_1;       /*This is a function which returns a refcursor*/
  loop
    fetch z bulk collect into test1;
    exit when z%NOTFOUND;

    select column_value bulk collect into x from  table(test1);
  end loop;

  open y for select employee_id,first_name from employees a where not exists 
           (select employee_id from table(x) where a.employee_id=employee_id);

  return y;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, using `x`, `y`, `z`, and `test1` as variable names makes it relatively hard to understand your code since it is not obvious at any point which variables represent a cursor and which represent a collection.  Calling an `object` `type_record` is also confusing since it is not, in fact, a `record` which is a PL/SQL structure very similar to a SQL object.  Additionally, your title is rather confusing since neither of your collections are actually associative arrays.

Second, your loop as currently constructed doesn't make any sense.  If you're going to have a loop, you'd want to do a `bulk collect` with a `limit`.  If you're not going to use a `limit` in your `bulk collect`, there is no point in looping since you'll only ever have one iteration of the loop.

Third, there appears to be no reason to copy the data from one collection to another.  You can use the data in `test1` to open `y` rather than using `x` in the query.  Using a second collection just means that you're wasting valuable space in the PGA.

Fourth, if you really do want to copy the data from one collection to another, you can do a simple assignment

```
x := test1;
```

Fifth, if you're going to write a `select` against a collection defined on an object type, the columns in the result will be the names of the object type's attributes.  `column_value` is only a column name for collections of built-in types.  If you really, really wanted to so the assignment the hard way with a `select` statement, you'd do something like

```
SELECT type_record( employee_id, first_name )
  BULK COLLECT INTO x
  FROM TABLE( test1 );
```